# Need good explanation of this small python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am actually following python on solo learn and came across this little code. Need a good explanation of this one. Thank you.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def do_twice(func, x, y):
    return func(func(x, y), func(x, y))

a = 5
b = 10

print(do_twice(add, a, b))
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly needs to be explainded?

Comment: Seems very straightforward. What is `func(func(x, y), func(x, y))` when `func` is `add`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do_twice(add, a, b))

add(add(x, y), add(x, y))
```

this function will return (x+y)*2

```
param 1 (func) => add(num1, num2)
param 2 (x) => a number
param 3 (y) => another number
```

num1 will be x+y

num2 will be x+y

so the value of do_twice will be ((x+y)+(x+y)).

I'm improving my English, be patient. I hope that explanation help's you

Comment: thank you! after repeating it to understand better, i've got it now. thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

`do_twice` get a function and two parameters.

then return below result:

```
func(func(param), func(param))
```

In this specific example:

```
add(add(5,10), add(5,10)) = add(15, 15) = 30
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, i just got confuse when i saw it , didn't saw that add function , any way thanks.